# XML to Java using JAXb print input XML to Eclipse Console

Tags: java, printing, jaxb

How can I print my XML file to the console after I have parsed it using JAXb. The XML has one root level and then there is a series of different table structure.

public class ExternalImports {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        // create JAXB context and initializing Marshaller

        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ServiceModel.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

        // specify the location and name of xml file to be read
        File XMLfile = new File(
                "C:\\Users\\Data.xml");

        ServiceModel model = (ServiceModel) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(XMLfile);
        System.out.println(model);
```

The XML Structure(Sample Code)

```
<Service-Model>
<component_t action="str1234">
    <type>12</type>
    <name>str1234</name>
    <attributes>str1234</attributes>
    <component_heirarchy>
        <supplier>str1234</supplier>
    </component_heirarchy>
    </sqm_component_t>
    </Service-Model>
```

I am trying to find a way a one or two line code to print it all on console. Otherwise its a tedious job to write 50 to 60 Lines of print statement

That's all I get on the console.

com.group.project.serviceModelTools.ServiceModel@77396f71

Comment: Jaxb fills a Java class from the xml... if you want to print the xml just read it from the file, no need for jaxb here. If you want to print the content of the object, then you have to implement the toString Method in your class. Your IDE should provide a functionality to generate this method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method serializes any POJO java class to a formatted xml string:

```
    public String serialize( Object aMessageDto) throws Exception
    {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance( aMessageDto.getClass());
        Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty( Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty( Marshaller.JAXB_NO_NAMESPACE_SCHEMA_LOCATION, SCHEMA_FILE);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        marshaller.marshal( aMessageDto, sw);
        return sw.toString();
    }
```

Just call it:

```
    System.out.println( serialize( myObj));
```

Comment: I just used the toString it gave me successful results

 public String toString() { values
 return}